# cakephp-2.4:Image directory not sending after applying jshelper ajax submission

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Here cakephp image upload working fine without ajax.After using ajax, data is inserted without image directory.

Here is my model code

```
public function processCoverUpload($check = array()) {
            if (!is_uploaded_file($check['product_image']['tmp_name'])) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            if (!move_uploaded_file($check['product_image']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $check['product_image']['name'])) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $this->data[$this->alias]['product_image'] = 'uploads/'. $check['product_image']['name'];
            return TRUE;
        }
```

Here the controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->MadProduct->create();

            $data = $this->request->data['MadProduct'];
                        if (!$data['product_image']['name']) {
                            unset($data['product_image']);
                        }
            if ($this->MadProduct->save($data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The mad product has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The mad product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
```

Here is the view file field

```
echo $this->Form->input('product_image',array('type' => 'file','label' => false,));
```

Here is the js submission button

```
 <?php  echo $this->Js->submit('Submit',array(
        'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn',array('speed' => 'slow')),
        'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut',array('speed' => 'slow')),
         'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
         'style'=>'width:45%;margin-top:1%;height:30px;')
         );   
  ?>
```

How I will send image directory by jshelper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS helper doesn't support file uploads, which would require making use of the "new" [**XHR2**](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) features.

You could extend the JS helper/engine and add support for files, but since the JS helper is [**deprecated**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) anyways, I'd suggest to simply make use of JavaScript directly. There are more than enough examples out there showing how to upload files via AJAX.

**[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)**